# Connection Strings in the Code and Continuous Deployment

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, apache-zookeeper, continuous-deployment, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to setup connection string is my Azure resource deployment project. Which will be triggered via Octopus.We would like to have a clean system with every deployment. We want to accomplish Continuous deployment.  The projects should cope with changes.And the system should be ready for blue green deployments ?

I am thinking about

- I.Using a load balancer and configurations point to the load balancer with the connection strings.
- II.Have a different database names at every deployment so every resource is unique every time.

What are the challanges I would face ? Do I have to have a tool like **ZooKeeper**?

**Project Structure by TYPE using Azure Resource Project**

[image]

**Parameters & variables focusing to keep them less than 20**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would advise the use of Jenkins in this scenario to achieve continuous deployment. I have implemented this successfully.

There is a feature called poll SCM. This will cause a build when you have a new commit.
[image: Poll SCM in Jenkins]

After the build, you can use the tool octo.exe to create a release and deploy that release to your specific environment.

I use the following code to create and deploy the release:

Create Release:

```
octo.exe create-release --project=%Environment% --server %Server% --apiKey %APIKEY% --version %version% --packageversion %version%
```

My variables are defined at a higher level to provide loose coupling:

%Environment%: Octopus Environment
%Server%: Octopus Server
%APIKEY%: API Key
%Timeout%: Timeout expiry

Deploy Release:

```
octo.exe deploy-release --project %Environment% --releaseNumber %version% --deployto %Environment% --server %Server% --apiKey %APIKEY% --progress --deploymenttimeout %Timeout%
```

Jenkins is very flexible and helps a lot in Continuous Deployment. You can have different jobs:

one for green and one for blue

After green is completed, you can trigger one for blue. As for database changes, you can use powershell together with sql cmd to alter your database and/or execute scripts.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario you can create a deployment slots and use the Auto-swap feature. This will reduce the downtime and risk. See this for more details:
[Configure Auto Swap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing#configure-auto-swap)
[image]

Also, for the first question, you can create 2 databases, one for production and one for staging. You can use sticky settings as shown below to stick  a DB to a specific slot. See this: [Configuration for deployment slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing#configuration-for-deployment-slots)

[image]

Additionally, you can also warm-up your slot so that it is ready to serve requests before it gets swapped.

HTH!

Comment: The problem with web apps and deployment slots are not stable. They live on the same resource. I would like to have a clean system every time I deploy.

Comment: What do you mean by **not stable**?  can you please elaborate?

Comment: They live on the same resource. If one of them gives a stackoverflow error. All the apps on that resource are DEAD!

Comment: That is not correct. The web app and the slot run in 2 separate process and are not dependent on each other.

Comment: they depend on the machine(resource).  The resource is finite... Try it....

Comment: You mentioned stackoverflow error which would happen on a thread inside a process. In Azure Web App, one process cannot read other process data. There is a Process isolation.

Comment: Machine resources are always finite, but I will not relate that to a **StackOverFlow** error.

Comment: I can understand your good intentions. The reality is different. Microsoft is targeting small companies with out CI systems to accomplish the network swap on the same resources. It has pros and cons. There is only one resource...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148382/discussion-between-rifat-erdem-sahin-and-kaushal-kumar-panday).